# how to create a spreaded blurred overlay with css

Tags: html, css

I want to create a blur effect like the blue and green in the image[image]

```css
.right-wrapper {
width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.right-wrapper .backdrop-filter-top {   
  width: 70%;   
  height: 70%;  
  position: absolute;   
  left: 5%;     
  top: 5%;  
  background-color: #43d9ad;    
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 35%, 100% 100%, 75% 100%, 5% 90%, 0 20%);  
  opacity: 0.4;     
  filter: blur(87px); 
}

.right-wrapper .backdrop-filter-bottom {    
  width: 70%;   
  height: 70%;  
  position: absolute;   
  right: 5%;    
  bottom: 5%;   
  background-color: #4d5bce;    
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 100% 45%, 80% 100%, 10% 70%, 0 25%);   
  opacity: 0.4;     
  filter: blur(87px); 
}
```

```html
<div class="right-wrapper">
  <div class="backdrop-filter-top" />
  <div class="backdrop-filter-bottom" />
</div>
```

Dont want to add the radial gradients or even okay with radial gradients, but this kind of blur is not coming properly

Comment: Is using blur even necessary? Looks like something that could be solved with overlapping radial/linear gradients.

Comment: Change className to class in your HTML (otherwise nothing will take effect!) and put something in your divs so you can see the effect as you work with your code.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because i was using the clip-path, not sure why, so when i remove clip-path, it worked

I have used clip-path in the div, so the filter blur option doesn't work, after I remove the clip-path, the filter blur option works perfectly,

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? This answer as-is is of very low quality